# jQuery selector hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, selector

This is the content of my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <!-- The above DOCTYPE declaration tells the browser that this page conforms to HTML 5 standards -->
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="author" content="Chris" />
        <link href="jquery.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#message').hide();
    });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="message">Hello World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a file named jquery.js, which is a minified version of jQuery 3.3.1, and it is saved in the folder **js** in which my HTML file and CSS file are located. In this document, I am trying to hide the paragraph with the ID of *message* using the hide() function, but when I open up the file in a Google Chrome browser, the paragraph is still there.

Note: Clearly, I am new to JavaScript and the implementation of a jQuery library.

Comment: also post the console messages here

Comment: can you pls share exact file structure for html, css and js

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like your jquery file path is wrong. Can you try with `<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js">` if your html and jquery file both are in same folder

Comment: Updated code: <!DOCTYPE html>
   <!-- The above DOCTYPE declaration tells the browser that this page conforms to HTML 5 standards --!>
 <head>

  <meta http-equiv="author" content="Chris" />
  <link href="jquery.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</script>
 <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#message').hide();
 });
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p id="message">Hello World!</p>
 </body>
</html>   It still does not work.

Comment: then delete your </script> tag including before <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> (this is extra tag). may be it resolved your issue –

Comment: Important thing: You said *it is saved in the folder js in which my HTML file and CSS file are located*. If it is true then the path of the library should be: `<script src="./jquery-3.3.1.min.js">`

Answer (score 1):

OK. So I figured out what was going on. I am learning JavaScript from a book, and the book said to include the version number and the "min" extension into the HTML file when you are linking it to the JavaScript file, even if that it not the correct filename. Since my jQuery library is jquery.js, I just removed the version number and the "min" extension. Once I did that, the paragraph went away, per the hide() function. Thank you all for responding. This was just a failure to communicate between the book and my brain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- The above DOCTYPE declaration tells the browser that this page conforms to HTML 5 standards -->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="author" content="Chris" />
        <link href="jquery.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#message').hide();
    console.log($.fn.jquery);
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="message">Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The file name has nothing to do with it... But since you changed it both places (in code and the file itself)... Maybe the issue was loading it.

Comment: The console is your best friend. It has a tab where you can inspect each file load success. And many things.

Comment: The console actually pointed it out for me. Originally, I had the filename and file extension as "js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" even though the actual filename and extension was "jquery.js" When I ran the console, it told me that the file "js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" did not exist. I thought you had to put the version of the library and the the "min" part is as per some standard. Once I changed the value in the SRC attribute to what the file was called, the code worked.

Comment: The file name is just a string. Name it `stupid-thing.js` and it will work. It's a text file without any proprietary editor code inside... Just plain text. As opposed to MS Word files. (example).

Comment: I understand that the file name is just a string, but if you don't specify exactly what the correct file name is when you are trying to link your HTML to another file, whether it is a CSS file or a JavaScript file, then the connection will not be made. That was my failure. I put it the wrong filename and extension, the console correctly noted that it could not find the file with that filename in the directory to which I was linking my HTML file. Thanks, again, for mentioning the console. I had used it before, but it has been a long time.

Comment: *«(...all the assumption here...) then the connection will not be made»* is **false**. It was a folder hyararchy (or typo) mistake for sure.

Comment: Well, that statement is false, since my HTML file now corresponds with the logic I've present. Then again, you may be right, and it working may just be pure coincidence! I guess we'll leave that to the philosophers, eh?

Comment: The version number thing I asked you about was a test... To see if the lib was actually loaded. It would have returned `undefined` on not loaded. -- You can type in commands in the console...

Comment: When you say "loaded," do you mean all the jQuery content pasted into a Notepad file and saved?

Comment: No!. Loaded by the browser.

Comment: I thank you for the help. But you are wrong on the facts. I just changed value of the SRC attribute to "jquery.min.js," and when I reloaded Chrome, I saw the paragraph. And when I checked the Console, I got two error messages: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery.html:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at jquery.html:8"

Comment: The first one clearly indicates that you have to accurately type the correct filename and extension, or Chrome will not be able to find the file and thus load it. The second error is due to the first error, since there is no jQuery library to reference.

Comment: Sure.. Since you host the file instead of using a [cdn](https://cdnjs.com/), if you change the filename only in the code of the calling page... The match will fail and you will have those 2 errors.. Ok. enought on this.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 0):

A couple blindish mistakes... Assuming your jQuery lib is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- The above DOCTYPE declaration tells the browser that this page conforms to HTML 5 standards -->
<html> <!-- MISSING -->
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="author" content="Chris" />
  <link href="jquery.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!--/script--> <!-- WHAT? Commented out -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#message').hide();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="message">Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

A missing and an extra tags.
Tell me if it solves the weird thing.

Comment: Ok... Others are focusing on your jQuery lib loaded. Make that test in console: `console.log($.fn.jquery);`... It should output the version number.

Comment: Good eye on the extra </script> tag. I removed that. I put in the <html> tag on the second line. I reloaded the page, both in Chrome and Firefox, and I can still see the paragraph.

Comment: I downloaded the newest jQuery library from the jQuery website, put the contents in a Notepad file, and saved with a .js extension. I'm not sure what you mean by "test in console." Like I said, I'm brand new to JavaScript.

Comment: Ok... [Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)... Here is Xyce... Xyce, here is [Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). -- Be sure to explore ;) [A tutorial quickly found](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-developer-console).

Comment: Read about [code indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) also. It helps quick markup reading for a human.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
            <!-- The above DOCTYPE declaration tells the browser that this page conforms to HTML 5 standards -->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="author" content="Chris" />
        <link href="jquery.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#message').hide();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="message">Hello World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Modify your HTML as above.
I have remove extra `</script>` and add missing `<html>`.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem is you had a extra `</script>` tag. Just remove it.

```
 <html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="author" content="Chris" />
       <link href="jquery.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

       <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $('#message').hide();
           });
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id="message">Hello World!</p>
   </body>
 </html>
```